# VS Code debug breakpoint circle in line number

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints

very newbie question yet can't seem to find an answer from anywhere.
I tried to add a breakpoint in VSC, expecting to see it by the line, yet my editor doesn't show red circle as in the snapshot even though I added this line in settings:   "debug.showBreakpointsInOverviewRuler": true

Any advice on this? (image is a snapshot from web) [image]

Comment: what language is this? please provide code for a [mre]. please actually read what a [mre] is too.

Comment: seems the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/78136015/11107541. please consider [raising an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug_report.md). if you do, please comment here with a link to your issue ticket.

Comment: I’m not  sure if it has anything to do with language since it’s VSC that is supposed to add red dot in any file of any language for breakpoints

Comment: language could be related- more directly, what _extension_ you're suing for debug support in the language you're developing in. see also https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78046082/78046085

Comment: I see - I'm creating an app with Expo and JS, and selected debugger as Node.js - wonder if this is what you asked. Not sure of any more info of extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out what was happening. There was a user setting I copied from a lecture to mimick the environment used by the instructor in `settings.json` (that you can find with `ctrl + P` : open user settings (JSON)). I had to change the value to **true**

> "editor.glyphMargin": false

Hope others don't make similar newbie mistake (still can't understand why the instructor had this setting)