# How to get red breakpoints back in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not exactly sure why, but the breakpoints disappeared on the left side. How can I return them?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p544p.png)

Having gone through Settings, I didn’t find a solution to my problem, and along the way I lost the line numbers, but I got them back, ha

Comment: what do you see when you press `F9` on a line with code

Comment: seems the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/78133479/11107541. please consider [raising an issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug_report.md). if you do, please comment here with a link to your issue ticket.